# Should batch normalisation be applied before or after ReLU?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, relu, batch-normalization

I know that there has been some discussion about this (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/67gonq/d_batch_normalization_before_or_after_relu/) and [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/correct-order-of-batchnorm-and-relu/41086)), but I can't seem to find consensus.

The crucial thing that I haven't seen mentioned in these discussions is that applying batch normalization before ReLU **switches off half the activations**, on average. This may not be desirable.

In other words, the effect of batch normalization before ReLU is more than just *z-scaling* activations.

On the other hand, applying batch normalization after ReLU may feel unnatural because the activations are necessarily non-negative, i.e. not normally distributed. Then again, there's also no guarantee that the activations are normally distributed before ReLU clipping.

I currently lean towards a preference to batch normalization after ReLU (which is also based on some empirical results).

What do you all think? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Like you said, there has been a lot of discussion but no consensus. This surely means this is not a crucial decision, or that the best choice depends on the given problem. I would suggest to compare both ways if possible. I did this in one case and I think the "bad" way (BN-RELU) was a bit better. But it may be the opposite for other architectures and problems!